# Create a file in application bundle

Tags: ios, file, bundle, nsdata

My application creates an `NSData` from a song from the iTunes library. I wan't to write this to a file in the bundle ( the file doesn't exists ). How do I create a file there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

stavash is right; you can't save to the bundle. To save to the documents directory, do something like this:

```
NSString *documentsDir = (NSString *)[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *pathForFile = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameString];

[songData writeToFile:pathForFile atomically:YES];
```

And then to recover the contents of the file:

```
NSData *songData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathForFile];
```

Answer (score 3):

Just like stavash said, bundle is read only.  You can save it to documents directory instead.  Here is an example:

```
NSString *root = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [root stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourfilename.ext"];
[yourFileData writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't write to the bundle. Consider storing it in the documents directory.